# Trying to convert JQuery to Mootools - show hide using mouseenter and mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mootools, mouseenter

I am trying to port the code below to mootools 1.1 code but am having no luck

```
jQuery(document).ready(
function(){
    jQuery("div#fpss-nav_activator").bind("mouseenter",function(){
    jQuery("div#navi-outer").stop(true, true).show("slow");
    }).bind("mouseleave",function(){
    jQuery("div#navi-outer").stop(true, true).hide("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
window.addReady('domready', function() {
  var navi = $("navi-outer");
  $("fpss-nav_activator").addEvent('mouseenter', function() {
    navi.slide('in');
  }).addEvent('mouseleave', function() {
    navi.slide('out');
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. do I need to add a new Fx.Slide?
I receive the following error "navi.slide is not a function"